# How to type a compiler?

Tags: functional-programming, type-theory

Take two abstract machines and two instructions the semantics of which is encoded in the following fictional (functional) language:

```
class incr;
// preserves @code, increments @pc, increments @x
fn execA(state: {pc: i32, code: {(pc): incr}, x: i32}): {code: `state.code`, pc: `state.pc+1`, x: `state.x+1`} 

class incrBy2;
// preserves @code, increments @pc, adds 2 to @x
fn execB(state: {pc: i32, code: {(pc): incrBy2}, x: i32}): {code: `state.code`, pc: `state.pc+1`, x: `state.x+2`}
```

Where `{(i): i32}` is a subtype of `[string, i32, f64]` iff `i == 1`, so the `state.code` is a tuple of instructions. Moreover we have expression types which are singleton types inhabited only by the given expression (think of path dependent types in scala).

**Statement**: given the code `[incrBy2]` it can be rewritten to `[incr, incr]`

**Question:** How would you formalize (in our fictional language) the above statement?

Comment: By writing `fn execB(state): execA(execA(state))`?

Comment: It's totally unclear what your question has to do with types.

Comment: I'm sorry if it is unclear, it is because I have trouble even stating the question I'm trying to answer :( I'm probably first looking for the formalization of the as-if rule, and then a function signature taking a code (containing incrBy2) which replaces each with two incr's while preserving this as-if rule

Comment: and as a further step we could make execA incrementing not "x" but an other member like "eax", so we also have to establish a kind of mapping between the types representing the states

Comment: The formalisation of the as-if rule is probably going to be a [rewrite system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_system) for your fictional language.

Comment: "*a kind of mapping between the types representing the states*" - I guess there's your problem. The states should not be represented with different types (`class`es in your pseudocode?), every state should be an instance of one and the same type. The different instructions should be members of an `enum` (or sum type), but there's only one `State` type able to represent all states of your abstract machine.

Comment: I thought I needed multiple State types as I have multiple state machines, take a machine which takes an instruction "x++" incrementing the value mapped to a variable "x", thus operating on a state like {locals: {x: i32, y:i32},...}, and the the "cpu" which takes an instruction "0x62618" incrementing the "eax" register thus operating on a state like {pc: i32, registers: {eax: i32, ebx: i32}, flags: ...}

Comment: It'd be better to phrase this question in Coq or Agda.

Comment: @Adam Yes, those look like separate state machines with separate types (for separate languages operating on different abstract machines), but the `incr` and `incrBy2` you presented in the question appear to belong to the same language.